# extract variable between {{}} using Regex

Tags: regex, regex-group, regex-negation

I have a string in this format `{{varx.vary}}, {{varz.varu}} and {{var1.var2.var3}` i have written a regex expression `([^{}]+)` that match all the fields between {} but am not able to get it to work for fields between double {{}} and ignore if only single curly bracket from one or both sides

Comment: Use `{([^{}]+)}` and grab capture group #1

Comment: it doesn't work the expression you provided included {} from each side of the fields am only interested on the variables that have {{ }}

Comment: I also wrote *grab capture group #1*. If your regex engine supports lookarounds then use: `(?<=\{)[^{}]+(?=})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: `{{([^{}]+)}}`
This will make sure that whatever we are getting will be between `{{}}`